# When do we need to mention/specify the type of integer for number literals?

Tags: c++, c, types, integer

I came across a code like below:

```
#define SOME_VALUE 0xFEDCBA9876543210ULL
```

This `SOME_VALUE` is assigned to some `unsigned long long` later.

**Questions**:

1. Is there a need to have postfix like `ULL` in this case ?
2. What are the situation we need to specify the type of integer used ?
3. Do C and C++ behave differently in this case ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, a hexadecimal literal gets the first type of `int`, `unsigned int`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `long long` or `unsigned long long` that can represent its value if it has no suffix. I wouldn't be surprised if C++ has the same rules.

You would need a suffix if you want to give a literal a larger type than it would have by default or if you want to force its signedness, consider for example

```
1 << 43;
```

Without suffix, that is (almost certainly) undefined behaviour, but `1LL << 43;` for example would be fine.

Comment: I suspect that the behavior of `1 << 43` is almost certainly not undefined (meaning it could blow up your computer), but is most likely unportable (meaning it might do something different on my computer vs. your).

Comment: Section 6.5.7 (n1570): "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undeﬁned." Unless your `int` has at least 43 bits, it's undefined behaviour. It will probably produce a 0 or a 512, but it is undefined.

Comment: @Gabe: It's undefined. Some processors trap arithmetic overflows. I doubt any will blow up by design, but it could kill the program.

Comment: So it's not defined whether the behavior is undefined. On an architecture with 64-bit ints the behavior is defined, while on an architecture with 32-bit ints the behavior is undefined. I guess I should have expected that. On my computer `1 << 43 == 2048`.

Comment: @Gabe: Until the mid noughties, 99.9% of 32-bit compilers would evaluate `1<<43` as `ARBITRARY_VALUE ? (1<<11) : 0`, with no side effects; they wouldn't necessarily be consistent about when it returned 2048 and when they returned zero, but they wouldn't do anything else.  Modern compilers, however, may ignore any code which would only be relevant if a program received data that would lead to an oversized shift (or cause other UB) which may of course render everything else in the program meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

1. I think not, but maybe that was required for that compiler.
2. For example, `printf("%ld", SOME_VALUE);` if `SOME_VALUE`'s integer type is not specified, this might end up with the wrong output.

Answer (score 2):

A good example for the use of specifying a suffix in C++ is overloaded functions. Take the following for example:

```
#include <iostream>

void consumeInt(unsigned int x)
{
    std::cout << "UINT" << std::endl;
}

void consumeInt(int x)
{
    std::cout << "INT" << std::endl;
}

void consumeInt(unsigned long long x)
{
    std::cout << "ULL" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    consumeInt(5);
    consumeInt(5U);
    consumeInt(5ULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Results in:

> **INT
>
>   UINT
>
>   ULL**

Answer (score 0):

When you don't mention any suffix, then the type of integral literal is deduced to be `int` by the compiler. Since some integral literal may overflow if its type is deduced to be `int`, so you add suffix to tell the compiler to deduce the type to be something other than `int`. That is what you do when you write `0xFEDCBA9876543210ULL`.

You can also use suffix when you write floating-pointer number. `1.2` is a `double`, while `1.2f` is a float.

Comment: No, the type is chosen based on the value.

Comment: @R..: I don't think that is true in C++.

Comment: @Nawaz It is.  C++ is identical to C here, see section 2.14.2 of the standard.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need suffixes if your only intent is to get the right *value* of the number; C automatically chooses a type in which the value fits.

The suffixes are important if you want to force the *type* of the expression, e.g. for purposes of how it interacts in expressions. Making it long, or long long, may be needed when you're going to perform an arithmetic operation that would overflow a smaller type (for example, `1ULL<<n` or `x*10LL`), and making it unsigned is useful when you want to the expression as a whole to have unsigned semantics (for example, `c-'0'<10U`, or `n%2U`).